# OpenGL method number value

Tags: javascript, opengl, methods, lwjgl

I have seen OpenGL codes written like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(1,1,1,1,1,-1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

and I have seen OpenGL codes written like this:

```
glEnable(2896);
glDisable(3042);
```

Notice the number values in the `glEnable()` and `glDisable()` methods.

My real question is: Does anyone have a link to a website that has a list of every method or which number value corresponds to whichever mode you are putting in the code? Like, what does `glEnable(2896);` actually mean?

Comment: Whoever wrote the code using those magic numbers needs to be shot. At the very least, use base-16 values so that you can look up the enum by value.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Shooting that guy is far to benign IMHO. I'm open for suggestions for harder punishments.

Comment: @datenwolf: The Human Rendering Pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enum names and values live in [`gl.xml`](https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/doc/registry/public/api/gl.xml), off of the main [spec registry page](http://www.opengl.org/registry/#specfiles).

Given your example of `glEnable(2896)`:

1. `2896` in hex is `0x0B50`
2. Searching gl.xml for that value lands you on

   `<enum value="0x0B50" name="GL_LIGHTING"/>`
3. Which you can see corresponds to `GL_LIGHTING`

Answer (score 2):

The numbers are the numeric values for OpenGL tokens as defined by the OpenGL specification. You can find the specifications for the various OpenGL versions at http://www.opengl.org/registry/

The definitions for the tokens is written down in a form usable by a C or C++ compiler in the `GL/gl.h` header file.

However it's strongly discouraged to use the numeric values, since in code they're just magic numbers.

> Like, what does glEnable(2896); actually mean?

Just search the `GL/gl.h` for the token which is defined to this value. They're usually written in hexadecimal so you have to convert that decimal representation first. Like this (using a *nix style shell):

```
dw ~ % grep $(printf '%X' 2896) /usr/include/GL/gl.h
#define GL_LIGHTING                             0x0B50
```